# Hive to support unsigned numeric data type

Tags: hadoop, types, hive

I'm  trying to load data which is usually in unsigned integer and unsigned Bigint into hive table. As Per the Hive Documentation, i see that it only supports signed integer and signed big integer

> INT/INTEGER (4-byte signed integer, from -2,147,483,648 to
>   2,147,483,647)  BIGINT (8-byte signed integer, from
>   -9,223,372,036,854,775,808 to 9,223,372,036,854,775,807)

Is there a way to store unsigned numeric values (tinyint, smallint, int,bigint) into Hive tables ?

Comment: What is your problem with using a signed *type* to store an unsigned *value* -- you fear that the value may be above the Max (e.g. 3,000,000,000 for an INT)? The Hive documentation recommends to use a `DECIMAL(x,0)` to store an integer value of at most `x` digits where `x` is above the capacity of a BIGINT (and as long as `x` <= 38).

Comment: Yea, i was thinking of how to store max values for given numeric type. So by using decimal can we store the unsigned max int value or big int value.

Comment: @samson Thanks. i was looking to store max unsigned int/bigint values. The decimal(x,0) is working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short story long: excerpts from the [Hive documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Types#LanguageManualTypes-decimal) about `DECIMAL` data type

> The `DECIMAL` type in Hive is based on Java's `BigDecimal` which is
>   used for representing immutable arbitrary precision decimal numbers
>   ... **limited to 38 digits** ...
>  As of Hive 0.13 users can specify
>   **scale and precision** when creating tables ...
>    ¤ if
>   scale is not specified, it defaults to 0 (no fractional digits) 
>     ¤ if no precision is specified, it defaults to 10.
>   Integral literals larger than BIGINT must be handled with DECIMAL(38,0). The Postfix *BD* is required ...

So `DECIMAL` is definitely the data type that you were looking for.